# What does this debug info tell me about what's going wrong with my attempted SSH connection?

Tags: linux, macos, networking, ssh

I'm trying to make a new connection to a remote server using supplied username & password credentials. I attempt to connect with this command:

```
ssh -vv -p {port} {user}@{host}
```

I get this output, and then it stops for 3 minutes:

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to {host} [{host}] port {port}.
debug1: Connection established.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.3a Server (Debian) [{host}]
```

And then I get this:

```
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 421 Login timeout (300 seconds): closing control connection

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Is it trying to connect using a public key? And if so, is that coming from my client, or from the server?

Testing the theory that this could be coming from my client, [I attempted to force password authentication by using the command given here](http://makandracards.com/makandra/1326-force-ssh-client-to-use-password-authentication-instead-of-public-key):

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@host
```

But I get the same output with -vv and it stops at the same point. I am never asked for a password.

Is this likely to be a client or a server problem? What are some next steps I can take to pinpoint the issue? The server is not administered by me- it would be good to know what to ask for when I am investigating the issue with the server administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh_exchange_identification: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.3a Server` tells you that an FTP server, not a SSH server, seems to be listening at `{port}`.

Comment: You are correct, they've given me the FTP server details.